# e.preventDefault() works only on the second time

Tags: jquery, events, preventdefault

So, i have such problem: first time, then the `<a>` get clicked `e.preventDefault()` isn't working and I jump to the top of the page, but on the second time it works. What is the problem?

```
$('#more a').live('click', function(e) {
    var last = $('p.post').last().data('id');
    console.log('start');
    if (last != '1') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://live.iappleworld.ru/ajax_more_mobile.php",
            data: "last=" + last,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#more a').text('').prepend('<img src="http://live.iappleworld.ru/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading"/> Loading...');
            },
            success: function(html) {
                $("#more").remove();
                $(html).hide().appendTo('ul.pageitem').slideDown(600);
            }
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Before and after i have another script.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in such a way that it renders answers meaningless.  I'm rolling it back.  Make your edit as an addendum or make comments on the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#more').on('click','a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // at the beginning stop page reload

  // your code

});
```

---

#### About `.on()`

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event handling:

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction)
```

Where `container` is any `Static element` within which the `target` element belong and of course container should belong to DOM at page load i.e it should not dynamic.

Read more aboue **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

---

#### Note

Try to avoid `.live()` if you have choice to use `jQuery >= 1.7` and bind delegate event with `.on()`.

---

#### According to comment

You've wrote

```
$('#more').live('click','a',function(e) {...});
```

but it should be

```
$('#more').on('click','a',function(e) {...});
```

---

#### Another option is change `a` tag `href` to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

and remove `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Refresh and now works again.
Can you see it: live.iappleworld.ru/mobile.php

Comment: @user1486339 I was a mistake and I edited that, please check my update code

Comment: The information is correct, but it doesn't change the result, and it doesn't say anything about why the code isn't working.

Comment: @Guffa Sir, It was a mistake in my previous code and I edited that now. Just `container` and `target` replaced with each other. I think my correct code is just fine now.

Comment: see it, please: live.iappleworld.ru/mobile.php
Button in the bottom of the page, looks like: "Загрузить еще"

Comment: @user1486339 try this `$('#more a').on('click', function(){...})` and comment me.

Comment: And another problem, with `on` event happens only first time

Comment: @user1486339 try this with in anchor tag `href` `<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>` and back to one step previous very step of `on()`

Comment: Hooray! Thank you! That was the problem

Comment: @thecodeparadox: Using `javascript:void(0)` in the link doesn't solve the problem with `preventDefault`, it just make something different happen when the link is activated, and that thing is just that the browser doesn't navigate anywhere. The link is still activated, the `preventDefault` call still doesn't work.

Comment: @Guffa OP has got solution with that... Now its on OP

Comment: In that case you should remove the call to `preventDefault`, as it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .live method, use `delegate`. I'm not sure about your html structure however i think this might work.

```
$('#more').delegate('a','click', function(e) {
  var last = $('p.post').last().data('id');
  console.log('start');
  if (last != '1') {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://live.iappleworld.ru/ajax_more_mobile.php",
        data: "last=" + last,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#more a').text('').prepend('<img src="http://live.iappleworld.ru/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading"/> Loading...');
        },
        success: function(html) {
            $("#more").remove();
            $(html).hide().appendTo('ul.pageitem').slideDown(600);
        }
    });
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like none of the javascript file is being loaded on the first visit to the page. Then you click the link and it is followed "normally", this refreshes the page and loads your javascript which then intercepts your click events from then on, as you expected.

Is the area with the (un)affected links on it loaded via ajax?